# Difference between Google In-App Updates with KTX and without KTX

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-update, google-play-core

Planning to implement In-App Updates in a project that is available in Play Store. However I have a question for the setup.

Sine the project is in Kotlin, can we add the `ktx` dependency only and leave the first one?

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.0.0' // Is this needed?
implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.0.0'
```

I know that KTX are those dependencies that provides Kotlin Extension but in this case it seems that the documentation is requesting to add two dependency, unlike other dependency for example from Firebase where KTX also includes the whole SDK + Kotlin Extensions.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#setup

Comment: Yes, the `ktx` one would actually be depending on the said library to add certain extension functions over apis. You can only add the `ktx` and it should work just fine.

Comment: @DarShan there is a phrase that says `also add`, not sure if it's suggesting that you should add the non ktx `as well as ` the one with the ktx. Anyway can you point me to a documentation or a thread that supports statement? Thanks

Comment: When you add the `ktx` version, it will also pull the default library which it depends on. I have personally added only the `ktx` versions & that works fine. Either way the `non-ktx` one will be added to the project.